# LLVM on MacOs - unknown type name 'template' in standard file iosfwd

Tags: c++, macos, clang-tidy

I installed LLVM on MacOS 10.13 using homebrew:

```
brew install --with-toolchain llvm
```

Then I exported required variables, based on [this guide](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/2/20/installing-clangllvm-on-osx).

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"
export CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
export LLVM_OPTIONS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib "\
"-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1/"
```

When running clang-tidy:

```
clang-tidy myheaderlib.h -- $LLVM_OPTIONS
```

I get errors, all of them are related to standard files:

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:96:1: error: unknown type name '_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD'
/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:100:1: error: unknown type name 'template'
...
```

What may be the cause?

Comment: I found out that clang-tidy treats myheaderlib.h as C code. __cplusplus along with other C++ related macros are not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I discovered, the problem was that clang-tidy by default treats `.h` files as C headers. Renaming it to `myheaderlib.hpp` fixed the issue. I'd still love to hear how to properly configure clang-tidy so that language can be specified regardless to the file extension.